# Determine how many stars to give from a portion of a score

Tags: c#

Math isn't one of my strong points, and I would like to know how to do this **properly** (I could hack somthing together, but it would be a mess):

- We score modules and give the user their score as a percentage
- We want to reward these scores with a star rating, but only if they achieve a score greater than the module pass mark
- The pass mark is variable
- For future proofing, lets say the number of stars to be awarded is also variable
- If they pass, I want them to always get at least 1 star

---

Example figures:

- Max Stars : 3
- Pass mark : 75 %
- User scores 75%, minimum passmark, so award 1 star
- User scores 90%, would this be 2 stars ??

Thanks guys.

---

Integrated solution

this is what I went with :

```
private const int NUMSTARS = 3;

public int starsFor(int pScore, int pPassMark)
{
    if(pScore < pPassMark)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (pScore == pPassMark)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {           
        return (int)Math.Ceiling(NUMSTARS * ((pScore - pPassMark) / (double)(100 - pPassMark))); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to figure out what should be the score range for 1 star, 2 star and 3 star?

Comment: @ searock - that AND how many stars a score then gets..

Comment: This could Spin off a Code golf!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Java implementation; C# translation should be straightforward. This assumes [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation):

```
    public static int starsFor(int mark, int passMark, int numStars) {
            if (mark < passMark) 
                    return 0;
            else if (mark == passMark)
                    return 1;
            else 
                    return (int) Math.ceil(
                            numStars * (
                                    (mark - passMark) / (double) (100 - passMark)
                            )
                    );
    }
```

Then we have ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Y8W77)):

```
System.out.println(starsFor(70, 75, 5)); // 0
System.out.println(starsFor(75, 75, 5)); // 1
System.out.println(starsFor(80, 75, 5)); // 1
System.out.println(starsFor(81, 75, 5)); // 2
System.out.println(starsFor(93, 75, 5)); // 4
System.out.println(starsFor(99, 75, 5)); // 5
System.out.println(starsFor(100, 75, 5)); // 5
```

---

#### C#/Variation

Here's a slight variation that handles extra points as well. It uses integer division, without requiring `double` cast and `Math.ceil`. [Ternary/conditional `?:` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28VS.80%29.aspx) is used (for style!).

```
  static int starsFor(int mark, int passMark, int maxMark, int numStars) {
    return
      (mark >= maxMark) ?
         numStars
         :
      (mark < passMark) ?
         0 
         :
      1 + numStars * (mark - passMark) / (maxMark - passMark);
  }
```

Then we have ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/U1Dqh)):

```
Console.WriteLine(starsFor(50, 75, 100, 5)); // 0
Console.WriteLine(starsFor(75, 75, 100, 5)); // 1
Console.WriteLine(starsFor(79, 75, 100, 5)); // 1
Console.WriteLine(starsFor(80, 75, 100, 5)); // 2
Console.WriteLine(starsFor(93, 75, 100, 5)); // 4
Console.WriteLine(starsFor(100, 75, 100, 5)); // 5
Console.WriteLine(starsFor(110, 75, 100, 5)); // 5 no extra stars!
```

Answer (score 3):

Following function may give you the expected result.
Logic I used:
- If passing marks are 75%, then 75%=1 star
- and you want to give max 5 stars to the user
- then divide remaining marks into 5 equal parts (75 to 80, 81 to 85, 86 to 90, 91 to 95 and 96 100)
- Apply the stars depending on this range.

```
public int RateMyUser(int MaxStars, int MinThreshold, int MarksObtained)
    {
        int division = 0;
        int stars = 0;
        // this will give division of remaining score greater than passing percentage<br>
        division = (100 - MinThreshold) / MaxStars;
        if (MarksObtained >= MinThreshold)
        {
            // obtain the stars to be given
            stars = (MarksObtained - MinThreshold) / division; // integer representing stars
            return stars + 1;
        }
        return stars;
    }
```

Comment: Put your sample code in code quotes to make it more readable ;0

Comment: you are right. Then I need to remove +1 from the first return statement. Also add one condition fore counting stars

if(MarksObtained == MinThreshold) { return 1; }

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what is the (expected) distribution of scores and what should be the distribution of stars.

For the simplest example of linear scores and linear stars, you can use the following:

```
Math.Max(0, ((score - passMark) / (100 - passMark) * (maxStars - 1)  + 1))
```

Comment: this seems to only give me one or three stars, never 2?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, even though it's C99

```
int GetStarCount(double scorePercentage, int maxStars, double PassMark)
{
  double classwidth = (1.0 - PassMark) / (double)(maxStars-1);
  double delta = scorePercentage - PassMark;
  if(scorePercentage < PassMark)
    return 0;
  return ceil(delta / classwidth)+1; 
}
```

**Update**
I should have written that the parameters are expected in the range of 0..1 in the first place... (Passmark of 75% == 0.75 as parameter value).

Comment: this had some unusual results, basically everything was given one star?